# How to create Tabbed Panel in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Which class i need to use for tabbed panel? Is there one?

i do the following and looks bad :-(

A tabbed navigation + a panel with and  0 padding between them-

```
    <div id="dashboardheader" class="container" style="padding-top: 20px;">
        <ul class="nav  nav-tabs tab-pane">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="dashboardpanel " style="padding-top: 0px">
        <div class="panel panel-primary container" style="padding-top: 30px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="row">
                        <img src="..\..\Content/Images/Dashboard/fgh.png" class="btn  btn-lg" role="button" onclick="OpenDialog()" />
                        <img src="..\..\Content/Images/Dashboard/fgh.png" class="btn  btn-lg" role="button" />
                        <img src="..\..\Content/Images/Dashboard/fgh.png" class="btn  btn-lg" role="button" />
                        <img src="..\..\Content/Images/Dashboard/fgh.png" class="btn  btn-lg" role="button" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="row">
                        <img src="..\..\Content/Images/Dashboard/fgh.png" class="btn  btn-lg" role="button" />
                        <img src="..\..\Content/Images/Dashboard/fgh.png" class="btn  btn-lg" role="button" />
                        <img src="..\..\Content/Images/Dashboard/fgh.png" class="btn  btn-lg" role="button" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

whats the alternate?

Comment: Please provide a Bootply

Comment: there is no "class" for this, as a class is user inputed, and can be what ever you want.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mnewt/4228037

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7WuNf/

Comment: this is what i meant -> "an overpriced template"--https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/tabs-control-tabbed-form-responsive-WB066F8J6

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I think what you want is just the regular [**bootstrap tabs**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tabs)

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
</div>
```

### [Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/2VmmW/)

With a little bit of styling, you can get it to look how you want:

[image: screenshot]

---

**For V4**, you'll want to style with the [`.nav-tabs` class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs) and also invoke the [tab JavaScript plugin](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#javascript-behavior)

Comment: thats what i did... its just nav and nav-tabs not tabbed panel. Did you check this? https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/tabs-control-tabbed-form-responsive-WB066F8J6

Comment: @user3801502, look at my updated fiddle. it's pretty darn similar to the theme you're trying to copy. Other than that, I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: how to make class fa fa-user working which you used. @KyleMit

Comment: @ASEN, not sure I understand your question.  Have you seen the fiddle? Have you tried `<i class="fa fa-user"></i>`?

Comment: haha sorry didn't mean to come off as unappreciative... Everything you have is working great for me I just can't get the box shadows to work correctly. Basically my "tab-pane" box shadow keeps overlapping the selected tab. It's tough for me to copy the code as its generated with a local db and some jQuery. Let me see if I can paste a picture of my rendered html and css styling

Comment: @KyleMit I can't paste the picture in comments but I think if you saw it you would know what I was talking about.. Is there a way to direct message you?

Comment: @KyleMit Looking at your JSFiddle you created and then my HTML,CSS to me they look identical (clearly I'm missing something). What I'm struggling with logically is how does your div "tab-panes" box shadow not overlay over the selected tab. Based on your CSS it looks like that is what should happen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109852/discussion-between-kylemit-and-shreddish).

Answer (score 6):

Here's some simple less you can add that allows you to include `.nav.nav-tabs` inside a `.panel .panel-heading`

An example codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/utGaK

IMHO it doesn't quite look as "clean" as the components are when used independently w/o additional styles..

I've tested it with `.panel-title` too using `.pull-right` on the `.nav`.  While it worked I found it best to add `.clearfix` to the header as the tabs are 1/2px too tall ATM.  Should be simple to resolve it.

Here's the code I use in the above example.

For example :

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
            <li><a href="#settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <!-- Tab panes + Panel body -->
    <div class="panel-body tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">HOME</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">PROFILE</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">MESSAGES</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">SET</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the less :

```
// Need to compensatve for padding in panel-heading
// Must be a way to invert this
// variable - @panel-heading-padding.  
@panel-heading-padding-negate: -10px -15px;

.panel {
    .panel-heading {
        .nav-tabs {
            margin:@panel-heading-padding-negate;
            border-bottom-width:0;

            > li {
                > a {
                    // re-apply the original padding 
                    padding:@panel-heading-padding;
                    margin-bottom:1px;

                    border:solid 0 transparent;
                    &:hover {
                        border-color: transparent;
                    }


                }

                &.active > a {
                    &, 
                    &:hover,
                    &:focused {
                        border:solid 0 transparent;                         
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### UPDATE

I've added the following to the `li` definition and removed the `margin-right` & `border-radius` on the `> li > a` so that when I pull the nav to the right of the header it fits & looks cleaner.

```
            &:first-child > a { 
                border-top-left-radius:@panel-border-radius;
            }
            &:last-child > a {
                border-top-right-radius:@panel-border-radius;
            }
```

Here's an updated codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hJsEC

Answer (score 3):

There's a Bootsnipp snippet that does this: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/MaA0A

It contains CSS to allow embedding tabs in the panel header like this:

```
<div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <!--...-->
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <!--...-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image: tabbed panel example]

Comment: That 300 lines of Css is very unattractive solution ! I was there before getting here so I got why u get down voted.... sorry

Answer (score 1):

Found a simple styling solution based on Andrew Scott's html structure:

```
.panel-heading>.nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: none;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <ul  class="nav nav-tabs  ">
      <li class="active" > <a href="#One" data-target="#One" data-toggle="tab"> One </a>  </li>
      <li  ><a  href="#Two" data-target="#Two" data-toggle="tab"> Two </a> <li>  
    </ul> 
  <div class="tab-content clearfix">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="One">
    This is one 
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade  " id="Two">
    This is Two 
    </div>
  </div>
```