# Twitter Bootstrap: Getting the index of an open tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the index of a tab when it opens in Twitter Bootstrap (3.3), but it keeps giving me an index of `0`. I've checked out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023473/how-can-i-get-the-clicked-or-active-number-of-tab) but `a)` it's apparently for an older version of Bootstrap (`shown` instead of `shown.bs.tab`, etc), and `b)` I tried to use an updated version of the code(`shown.bs.tab`) and it didn't work.

Any idea of how to do this in Bootstrap 3.3?

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  console.log($(e.target).index());
});
```

[I've created a JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/eazg9hoe/)

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `.parent()` to target the parent `li` instead of `$(e.target).index()` that get the index of `a` inside `li` (that way it's return always 0) :

```
$(e.target).parent().index()
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    console.log($(e.target).parent().index());
})
```

```css
body {
    margin: 5px;
    background: #A6A6A6
}

/* Tab Navigation */
.nav-tabs {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;    
}
.nav-tabs > li > a {
    background: #DADADA;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -8px 7px -9px rgba(0,0,0,.4),-2px -2px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
.nav-tabs > li.active > a,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover {
    background: #F5F5F5;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.4),-2px -3px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}

/* Tab Content */
.tab-pane {
    background: #F5F5F5;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    border-radius: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li class="active">
          <a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <icon class="fa fa-home"></icon> Home
          </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
          <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Profile
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Messages
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Settings
          </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="home">
          <h2>Home Content Goes Here</h2>
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/cats/1" alt="Cats"/>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
          <h2>Profile Content Goes Here</h2>
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/cats/2" alt="Cats"/>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="messages">
          <h2>Messages Content Goes Here</h2>
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/cats/3" alt="Cats"/>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="settings">
          <h2>Settings Content Goes Here</h2>
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/cats/4" alt="Cats"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    
</div>







<!-- Post Info -->
<div style='position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;    
            background:lightgray;width:100%;'>
    About this SO Question: <a href='http://stackoverflow.com/q/24553105/1366033'>How to create Tabbed Panel in Bootstrap</a><br/>
    Fork This Skeleton Here: <a href='http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/kcpma/'>Bootstrap 3.0 Skeleton</a><br/>
    Styled after this (better) template: <a href='http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB066F8J6'>Responsive Tabbed Form</a><br/>                
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to get the index of some element relative to a set of elements. Try this instead:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  console.log($('a[data-toggle="tab"]').index($(e.target)))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the parent `li` of the the current a by using `.closest()` and find its `index`.

```
 $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
      alert($(this).closest('li').index());
    })
```

Working example : **http://jsfiddle.net/eazg9hoe/1/**

Answer (score 0):

`$(e.target).index()` will get the index of the element in relation of the parent. Since you are firing from the `<a>` and the parent is the `<li>` the index will always be 0.

If you jump up to the parent(`<li>`) and find the index of that since you will be checking the index of the `<li>` in relation to the `<ul>` you will get the correct index.

```
console.log($(e.target).parent().index());
```

If you did want to find out the index of the tab in relation to all of the `$('a[data-toggle="tab"]')` items. You could also use `$.inArray(object,array)`

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var index = $.inArray(e.target,$('a[data-toggle="tab"]'))
    console.log(index);
});
```

**Examples here:**

http://jsfiddle.net/zdd96tc6/